# How do I Run Code in Wingware?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am utilizing Wingware 6.0 Personal for utilization in Python 3.6. I'm trying to run some basic coding, which works fine in the Python shell, but for some reason I cannot seem to get it to appear; instead, when I attempt to run the code, it attempts to debug my code. I'm new to coding, so it's probably self explanatory, but how do I get my coding to work?[screenshot of wingware software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aflTK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Wingware 6, the green "run" button in the GUI is really two functions:

- START till next break point (if it was not running before)
- CONTINUE till next break point (if it was running till break point)

It will always run in the debugger when trying to run in the GUI. This is by design.

More information can be found in section 8.2 of Wingware Help. Goto the "Help" pull down menu, choose "Wing Manual"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not a pro at Python but I have learn python and used Wingware. Wingware may fail to start the debug process in certain cases. If this happens, it often helps to try debugging a small test.

You can use the Step Into command from the Debug menu to cause Wing to attempt to run only as far as the first line of your code. This rules out possible problems caused by specific code.

Then check through the following common problems. For information on obtaining additional information from the debug sub-system, refer to the Diagnostic Output section

Requires TCP/IP
Selecting Python Version
Setting PYTHONPATH
Environment Conflicts
Corrupt Python Install